# What used to CS:GO's default radio bindings?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I stopped playing CS:GO for few months and only returned few days ago to notice I only have bind z radio and none of the other radio bindings. I tried binding them myself but it doesn't feel right.

If I'm not imagining it, and they did change the defaults recently, what used to be  the X,C and V bindings ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bind "c" "radio2"
bind "z" "radio1"
bind "x" "radio"
```

In the Danger Zone Update, they rebound `x` to the Health Shot, and altered the other ones too.